# SQL update a value within a string from another column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a column which contains a string within this string their is a GUID see below called `voucherID`, I would like to replace this GUID from another column on the same row.

```
<VoucherID>6c1c5c4f-3bab-4804-9a92-80b34f448cfe<VoucherID>
```

any help appreciated.

There are around 6000 rows.

Comment: Is the `GUID` to be replaced different on each row or the same? And what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What **datatype** (and name) is your column that holds the XML-enclosed GUID ??

Answer (score 1):

IF on Oracle try

```
UPDATE YourTable T SET
T.YourXMLColumn = SUBSTR ( T.YourXMLColumn, 1, INSTR ( T.YourXMLColumn, '>' ) + 1 ) || 
                  T.YourValueColumn || 
                  SUBSTR ( T.YourXMLColumn, INSTR (T.YourXMLColumn, '<', -1 ) ) ;
```

Another option is just rebuilding the content with the new value

```
UPDATE YourTable T SET
T.YourXMLColumn = '<VoucherID>' || 
                  T.YourValueColumn || 
                  '</VoucherID>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you select the value in the right colomn and then make an update ?
If you've a lot of switches to do you can use a loop, offcours it can be realy slow but it's the easier way, I think...